# How can I auto increment the date in select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, jsp

I have this form, the purpose of this is filtering the data in a jsp page. This is working but so simple and not good I think, and just for 2013 and I would like to make it incremented. Is there any much better and simpler way to do it?

```
<% 
String First = request.getParameter("firstTo");
String Second = request.getParameter("secondTo");

request.setAttribute("First", First);
request.setAttribute("Second", Second);

Connection conn = (Connection) this.getServletContext().getAttribute("conn");
String query = "SELECT * FROM blood_chemistry JOIN consult USING (idconsult) JOIN patients USING (idpatients) WHERE release_date BETWEEN '" + First + "' AND '" + Second + "'  ORDER BY plastname ASC, pfirstname ASC";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); 
%>

<form method="post" action="blood.jsp">
<p style="color:white;">
    <select name="firstTo">
       <option value="01-01-2013">January</option>
       <option value="02-01-2013">February</option>
       <option value="03-01-2013">March</option>
       <option value="04-01-2013">April</option>
       <option value="05-01-2013">May</option>
       <option value="06-01-2013">June</option>
       <option value="07-01-2013">July</option>
       <option value="08-01-2013">August</option>
       <option value="09-01-2013">September</option>
       <option value="10-01-2013">October</option>
       <option value="11-01-2013">November</option>
       <option value="12-01-2013">December</option>
   </select>To:
   <select name="secondTo">
       <option value="01-31-2013">January</option>
       <option value="02-29-2013">February</option>
       <option value="03-31-2013">March</option>
       <option value="04-31-2013">April</option>
       <option value="05-31-2013">May</option>
       <option value="06-31-2013">June</option>
       <option value="07-31-2013">July</option>
       <option value="08-31-2013">August</option>
       <option value="09-31-2013">September</option>
       <option value="10-31-2013">October</option>
       <option value="11-31-2013">November</option>
       <option value="12-31-2013">December</option>
   </select>
</p></form>
```

---

I managed to do this but it's only the current date, I want to set it to like this 01-01-2013 but the year is only incrementing.. how can I do that?

```
<%
  Date dNow = new Date( );
  SimpleDateFormat ft = 
  new SimpleDateFormat ("MM--dd--yyyy");
  out.print( "<h1 align=\"center\">" + ft.format(dNow) + "</h1>");
%>
```

Comment: explain in more detail what `make it incremented` means...could mean duplicate select for other years, or dynamically generate year on server or...??

Comment: oh sorry... dynamically generate year, the 2013 will be 2014,etc

Comment: I know little about jsp...however surely you can find how to write out current year in a very simple web search....also how to get number of days in a month...not all months have 31. Every server language has comprehensive date/time libraries

Comment: @charlietfl I managed to searched in the net and I updated my question, kindly see

Comment: you can't figure out from that how to just get current year output? Just change the format

Comment: out.print("<option value='01-01- " + ft.format(dNow) + "'>January</option>") ... but error, i'm not familiar with this, how can I fix this? I'm getting the "yyyy" format

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the year dynamic you could do this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```